# Как придвинуть строки к друг другу

Tags: html

**Хочу приблизить максимально все строки друг к другу.**

**Класс dline не помогает.**

```
   p.dline {
    line-height: 0.1;
   }
   P {
    line-height: 0.1em;
   }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот по картинке можно все сразу сказать, не все конечно это могут делать, а только сотрудники РенТВ и вообще участники шоу "битва экстрасенсов" :)

вы бы html код и css-стили все таки показали бы для удобства

```css
div {
  width:        100%;
  height:       30px;
  line-height:  30px;
  padding:      10px;
  
  font-size:    36px;
  font-family:  Tahome;
  font-weight:  bold;
  color:        white;
  text-shadow:  2px 0 0 black, -2px 0 0 black, 0 2px 0 black, 0 -2px 0 black, 1px 1px black, -1px -1px 0 black, 1px -1px 0 black, -1px 1px 0 black;
}

hr {
  width:        50%;
  background:   linear-gradient(to right, yellow, red, magenta, blue, cyan, lime);
  border:       none;
  height:       5px;
}
```

```html
<div>строка 1</div>
<div>строка 2</div>
<div><hr /></div>
<div>Связь со мной</div>
```

вот ваш код:

у вас проблема в .gif картинке, которая очень высокая, это и даёт отступы перед картинкой и после картинки

```css
   .stroke {
    font: 2em Arial, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: black 1px 1px 0, black -1px -1px 0, 
                 black -1px 1px 0, black 1px -1px 0;
   }

  .text {
    text-align:  center;
   }

   p.dline {
    width:          100%;

    font-family:    impact;
    font-size:      32px;
    color:          white;
   }
```

```html
<div class="text">
        <p class ="stroke dline">Строка1</p> 
        <p class ="stroke dline">Строка2</p>
        <p class ="stroke dline">Строка3</p>
        <img src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/TIj8cbzWYKnE9ul3ab/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e477337c9d368e465eb7afce6e17cc209193699bf3b&rid=giphy.gif"></img>
        <p class ="stroke dline">Связь со мной</p> 
</div>
```

P.S.

и еще используйте css-стили, а не `<font>` который лет 20 уже как устарел и еще проверьте свой код - у вас тег `<font>` был не закрыт (забыта скобка)

Comment: Как этот стиль интегрировать в код? У меня выдает ошибки вверху страницы. https://i.imgur.com/DLuPAT7.png

Comment: чтобы говорить про интегрирование надо увидеть ваш html код минимум - а я его на картинке не вижу

Comment: https://files.dp.ua/ru/E823SsP

Comment: файл не скачивается

Comment: https://files.dp.ua/ru/RkM46 - обновил

Comment: нет - не выходит
выложите тут сайт

Comment: все, смог загрузить - сейчас посмотр

Comment: добавил код в своей ответе - смотрите

Comment: Спасибо большое =)